# Custom order set to set without changing order

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I have a class with a set. I need a function which changes the order but which returns a normal set not a `set<whatever, order>`. All I need to respect in the following code is the header. How can I turn a set with its order changed back to a normal set?

```
// ... class stuff
public:
    set<int> s;
// ...
set<int> ord(){ 
        set<int, Order> aux;
        set<int> res;

        set<int>::iterator it = s.begin();
        while(it != s.end()){
            aux.insert(*it);
            it++;
        }

        // res = aux;

return res;
}
```

Thank you! :)

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Whatever you do, a `std::set` wil lat all times be ordered according to its comparator. I'm not sure what you want to do either, but if it is against that, you can't use a `std::set`.

Comment: Basically, I have a function which returns a `set<int>` and I need that function to use a different order which I have specified in a functor (`Order`). The question is, once I have the result in the `set<int, Order>`, how can I turn it back to a `set<int>` for the return value without changing the order?

Comment: Without changing the order, you can't.

Comment: Ok, then I'll have to find another way. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Without changing the order, you can't. – [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3233393/quentin)